# How to create a Strapi homepage

Tags: web, gatsby, strapi

I am creating a gatsby-strapi website.
I created a "Single Type" for the homepage, and it loads on currently it is on mysite.com/homepage
How can I make it load on mysite.com

Answer (score 0):

Check your page's slug. If your slug is `homepage`, that might be your problem. The slug for the homepage should be empty.